# Perl Regex expression to capture string between start and end of line (with end of line having a space with character)

Tags: regex, string, perl

My string of data is this:

```
(wlc-nyhy30-a) *
```

I need to strip off the beginning parenthesis and the end parenthesis that matches exactly `) *`.

My end string should be:

```
wlc-nyhy30-a
```

I can easily strip off the beginning `(` like below, but I'm having a very hard time getting Perl to match and remove end of line `) *`

Here is the first part that works:

```
$output{'prompt'} =~ s/^\(//;
```

Appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this `") *)` in the target string ?

Comment: @x15, I believe it should be should be ") *", as in "`) *`"

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
s/^\((.*)\)\s\*$/$1/
```

Explanation:

```
^          beginning of the string
\(         opening parenthese - needs to be escaped with \
(.*)       ...a capturing group...
\)         closing parenthese - needs to be escaped with \
\s         a single space
\*         a star - needs to be escaped
$          end of the string
```

This matches the string as a whole, hence it will apply on the example you provided as an example (`(wlc-nyhy30-a) *`), while also leaving untouched other strings such as `(wlc-nyhy30-a) a`.

Demo:

```
my $string = "(wlc-nyhy30-a) *";
$string =~ s/^\((.*)\)\s\*$/$1/
print $string, "\n";
```

Yields:

```
wlc-nyhy30-a
```

Comment: May be reading more into it than what is known. Don't think he makes claim that the end is a prerequisite for the beginning or visa-versa, that would invoke a balanced open-close requirement. The original regex seemed fine[^\\(|\\)\s\\*$](https://regex101.com/r/IKNMdo/1)

Comment: @x15: well, it is hard to tell for sure. I initially read it like you, but then I changed it. OP is not commenting. Maybe I should edit my answer to show both solutions.